# When splitting code to a custom module in Nodejs when trying to pass a variable to another module its get undefined

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, node-modules

I have a aws lambda that I use to disable a AWS cloudwatchevents . It works fine when I am not using custom modules when I tried using custom modules I get undefined for a variable I need in another module. What I am doing wrong ?  var myRuleparams now is undefined
I didnt put the whole code just a snippet so it would be easy to understand

here is the index.js that works

```
let AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const cloudwatchevents = new AWS.CloudWatchEvents({region: 'us-east-1'});
//var cloudrule = require('./cloudrule');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

let myRule;
const er = event.resources ;

//miRule is the name of the CloudWatchEventRule that started the lambda
 myRule = er[0].slice(43);
 var myRuleparams = { Name: myRule };
 var rulePromise = cloudwatchevents.disableRule(myRuleparams).promise();
                                      rulePromise.then(
                                        function(data) {
                                         console.log("cloudwatchevent has been disabled");
                                          console.log(data);
                                        }).catch(
                                          function(err) {
                                          console.error(err);
                                          //this works 

                                          // more code
```

here is the index.js with custom module cloudrule.js that do not work

index.js

```
let AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const cloudwatchevents = new AWS.CloudWatchEvents({region: 'us-east-1'});
var cloudrule = require('./cloudrule');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

let myRule;
const er = event.resources;
//miRule is the name of the CloudWatchEventRule that started the lambda
myRule = er[0].slice(43);
var myRuleparams = { Name: myRule };

// here under custom module with functions and passing Variable myRuleparams
cloudrule.disableCloudWatchRuler(myRuleparams);

//more code
```

here is the cloudrule.js

```
let AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const cloudwatchevents = new AWS.CloudWatchEvents({region: 'us-east-1'});

module.exports = {

disableCloudWatchRuler: function(myRuleparams) {

                        var rulePromise = cloudwatchevents.disableRule(myRuleparams).promise();
                                      rulePromise.then(
                                        function(data) {
                                         console.log("cloudwatchevent has been disabled");
                                          console.log(data);
                                        }).catch(
                                          function(err) {
                                          console.error(err);
                                        });
                                    }
                                };
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it need to put let myRule;   before the module export to make it global variable

so code should look like this

```
let AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const cloudwatchevents = new AWS.CloudWatchEvents({region: 'us-east-1'});
var cloudrule = require('./cloudrule');
 //add let myRule here
let myRule;

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

//remove let myRulefrom here

const er = event.resources;
 // more code
```